# Modifying $scope Values for Angular Controller Unit Testing

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

All,

I have a unit test suite for a AngularJS controller that follows the pattern `beforeEach()`:

```
var ResourcesCtrl,
    scope, rootScope, loc, ctrl;

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $location) {
    scope = {};
    rootScope = {};
    loc = $location;
    ctrl = $controller;
    scope.instanceName = 'TestInstance';


    ResourcesCtrl = $controller('ResourcesCtrl', {
      $scope: scope,
      $rootScope: rootScope,
      $location: loc
    });
  }));
```

Then a bunch of `it()` blocks with assertions/expect that all work as expected.

Now what I need to do, in just one of the test cases I'm adding, is change the value of `scope.instanceName`; however, it appears that even if I change its value inside the `it()` test case, that's not reflected in the scope of the controller. I have tried instantiating the controller with a new scope inside the test case, but that hasn't worked either.

So my question is the following: how can I change/override variables that were passed to the controller in the `beforeEach()` setup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that the call to `$controller` occurs in the beforeEach using whatever scope variables are available to it at that time. You want to be able to change the `scope` variable *before* the controller is called. One option is to use an `init` function which is called in each spec so that you can control exactly when the controller gets called:

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $location) {
  scope = {};
  rootScope = {};
  loc = $location;
  ctrl = $controller;
  scope.instanceName = 'TestInstance';

  this.init = function() {
    ResourcesCtrl = $controller('ResourcesCtrl', {
      $scope: scope,
      $rootScope: rootScope,
      $location: loc
    });
  }
}));

...

it("should do something", function() {
  scope.instanceName = "NewName";
  this.init();
  ...
});
```

Note that this means that `this.init` must be called in *every* spec in the file.

Comment: I wanted to avoid calling stuff in each spec, but, seems to do the trick. Thanks.

Comment: An alternative to having the `init` function in every spec is grouping `it` blocks together using `describe`.

Comment: Does this work if inside the Controller you are setting the value and you want to override that to a new value?  I tried to override the value like in your example, but when the Controller initializes, it changes it back to the original value.

Comment: @AronYsidoro in that case, you will have to modify the scope after the controller is run. If you are testing a method that the controller adds to the scope, then that should work fine. Run the controller, change the value, run the method, and check the returned value. If you're testing some other aspect of the controller, it might get tricky, depending on what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

in your beforeEach add $rootScope to the parameter list and assign the following variables like this

```
scope = $rootScope.$new();
rootScope = $rootScope;
```

since they come from angular's $rootScope you can call $apply() if needed.